How will Newton's rings look using a Concave-convex lens?
I want to examine lenses that are concave-convex (one for each side) using the Newton's rings method.
I'm trying to build the theoretical model for this, but I'm quite sure that the rays of light will not "converge" and interfere in a nice pattern, since refraction is not negligible in this setup.
Did anyone try this? Does anyone have a setup which allows for the pattern to appear in a concave-convex lens?

Are you trying to measure its focal length, or do you want to investigate the quality of the lens? Or perhaps you want to measure the curvatures?

One can see random Newton "rings" by pressing two glass slides against each other. I am pretty sure that these slides have a more or less random variation of their surface radii and both convex and concave patterns are showing up. I am not sure why there should be a difference.

To Noct: I'm trying to investigate the quality of the lens.
To FlatterMann: I'm trying to understand the optics of the specific lens instead of trying to recreate the "rings" as a phenomenon (I hope I understand your intentions correctly)
